Potential damage to tankless heater using citric acid and vinegar?
I began descaling my tankless water heater with 30% vinegar and citric acid.  After a few minutes the water turned blue.  I would like to know if this is something I should be concerned about.  I am worried that the descaling mixture may be doing damage to the copper. Or is it just some minor leaching due to the chemical interaction?
Found the answer elsewhere:
Do not use vinegar solutions exceeding 5% concentration to descale Rinnai products. Always dilute concentrated vinegar solutions to 5% using mixing ratios provided in Table 1 (next page).
Do not use concentrated vinegar solutions exceeding 45% to dilute with water to make a 5% vinegar solution.

I'm not a chemist, but the blue is likely to be copper acetate and/or copper citrate. I suggest that you use a weaker solution of only citric acid. Just a small amount of the copper salt can produce a lot of colour, so it is probably OK as long as you don't do it again, IMHO.

Re: "Found the answer elsewhere" -- it's okay to answer your own question, and that paragraph looks like a good answer.

You also need to check if they mean 5% vinegar(table) solution, or 5 percent of vinegar in water.  30%/45% vinegar is not what would be found in grocery stores, usually only regular 5% or 6.5% pickling vinegar.

...or you could have Read The Fabulous Manual before using excessive strength acids which seem to indicate that you did not, in fact, do that before choosing your own path to harming expensive equipment...

Yeah when I was descaling my car, I ran 1/4 cup citric acid powder to 2 gallons water. And it still took a bite and my water pump started squeaking.
